# Why is modifiedCount missing in Mongo bulkWrite() result?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, mongo-shell, bulkupdate

I'm on mongo v4.2. See the below mongo shell script which is an exact copy of the example from [mongo bulkWrite related documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#ordered-bulk-write-example)

```
db.pizzas.insertMany( [
   { _id: 0, type: "pepperoni", size: "small", price: 4 },
   { _id: 1, type: "cheese", size: "medium", price: 7 },
   { _id: 2, type: "vegan", size: "large", price: 8 }
] )

try {
   db.pizzas.bulkWrite( [
      { insertOne: { document: { _id: 3, type: "beef", size: "medium", price: 6 } } },
      { insertOne: { document: { _id: 4, type: "sausage", size: "large", price: 10 } } },
      { updateOne: {
         filter: { type: "cheese" },
         update: { $set: { price: 8 } }
      } },
      { deleteOne: { filter: { type: "pepperoni"} } },
      { replaceOne: {
         filter: { type: "vegan" },
         replacement: { type: "tofu", size: "small", price: 4 }
      } }
   ] )
} catch( error ) {
   print( error )
}
```

The actual bulkWrite result returned is as follows

```
{ 
    "acknowledged" : true, 
    "deletedCount" : 1.0, 
    "insertedCount" : 2.0, 
    "matchedCount" : 2.0, 
    "upsertedCount" : 0.0, 
    "insertedIds" : {
        "0" : 3.0, 
        "1" : 4.0
    }, 
    "upsertedIds" : {

    }
}
```

You will note that the `modifiedCount` field mentioned in the documentation is missing. Why is it not included? Is `matchedCount` an alternative?

I also tried another much simpler script to reproduce this

```
db.someCollection.insertOne({ "_id": 1, "field": "some-value" })    
var result = db.someCollection.bulkWrite([{
    updateOne: {
         filter: { "_id": 1 },
         update: { "$set": { "field": "another-value" } },
         upsert: false   
    }
}])
printjson(result)
```

I see the same behavior. No `modifiedCount`.

```
{ 
    "acknowledged" : true, 
    "deletedCount" : 0.0, 
    "insertedCount" : 0.0, 
    "matchedCount" : 1.0, 
    "upsertedCount" : 0.0, 
    "insertedIds" : {

    }, 
    "upsertedIds" : {

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems there is some shell issue, try to update your shell version and try again.

Comment: @turivishal I checked with v5.0.6 as well. No luck. I see the same behavior

Comment: I mean check the mongodb shell version, try to update it.. or download [shell from mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell) or use `mongosh`.

Comment: Either the issue is in the mongo shell or the documentation is not updated. It gives the above output only. The `matchedCount` is the one corresponding to the update queries.